# Showing that 4D rank-2 anti-symmetric tensor always contains a polar and axial vector

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, vectors, group-theory, representation-theory

In my special relativity course the lecture notes say that in four dimensions a rank-2 anti-symmetric tensor has six independent non-zero elements which can always be written as components of 2 3-dimensional vectors, one polar and one axial.

For instance in the angular momentum tensor $L^{ab} = X^aP^b -X^bP^a$ the top row $L^{0i}=ct\vec{p}-(E/c)\vec{x}$ which is obviously polar (as $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{p}$ are polar vectors) while the spatial-spatial section contains the usual 3D angular momentum components which obviously represent the axial angular momentum $\vec{L}$ vector. (And the first column is just -1 times the polar vector due to the anti symmetry of the tensor).

The notes only explain this as ‘these components transforming in identical ways to polar and axial vectors’. I would like to know how to show this, possibly from the co-ordinate transformation rule for a 4D rank 2 contravariant tensor by showing it has equivalent effects of transforming these vector components.

Specifically the notes say ‘it works because those elements do transform as a vector under rotations’. I’m also confused as to why rotations specifically as a transformation are mentioned here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Qmechanic's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/604525) is beautiful. I'll clarify one non-obvious detail, namely why the $\textbf{3}\wedge \textbf{3}$ transforms as a vector under the identity component of the rotation group. (It *doesn't* transform as a vector under reflections, which is why we call it an axial vector.)

Let $F_{ab}$ be an antisymmetric tensor in 4d spacetime, and use $0$ for the "time" index and $\{1,2,3\}$ for the "space" indices. When Lorentz transformations are restricted to rotations, the components $F_{jk}$ with $j,k\in\{1,2,3\}$ do not mix with the component $F_{0k}=-F_{k0}$, so we can consider only the components $F_{jk}$. These are the components of the $\textbf{3}\wedge \textbf{3}$ in Qmechanic's answer.

---

For the rest of this answer, all indices (including $a,b,c$) are restricted to the spatial values $\{1,2,3\}$.

The antisymmetry condition, $F_{jk}=-F_{kj}$, implies that this has only $3$ independent components, which is the correct *number* of components for a vector, but something doesn't seem quite right: Under rotations, the transformation rule for a vector only uses *one* rotation matrix, but the transformation rule for $F_{jk}$ uses *two* rotation matrices — one for each index. How can these possibly be equivalent to each other? Of course they're *not* equivalent to each other for rotations with determinant $-1$, which is why we call it an *axial* vector, but they *are* equivalent to each other for rotations with determinant $+1$, and the purpose of this answer is to explain why that's true.

Let $R_{jk}$ be the components of a rotation matrix whose determinant is $+1$. This condition means
$$
 \sum_{j,k,m}\epsilon_{jkl}R_{1j}R_{2k}R_{3m} = 1,
\tag{1}
$$
which can also be written
$$
 \epsilon_{abc} = 
 \sum_{j,k,m}\epsilon_{jkm}R_{aj}R_{bk}R_{cm}.
\tag{2}
$$
The fact that $R$ is a rotation matrix also implies
$$
 \sum_c R_{cm}R_{cn}=\delta_{mn},
\tag{3}
$$
which the component version of the matrix equation $R^TR=1$. Contract (2) with $R_{cn}$ and then use (3) to get
$$
 \sum_c\epsilon_{abc}R_{cn} = 
 \sum_{j,k}\epsilon_{jkn}R_{aj}R_{bk}.
\tag{4}
$$
Equation (4) is the key. The effect of a rotation on $F_{jk}$ is
$$
 F_{jk}\to \sum_{a,b}R_{aj}R_{bk}F_{ab},
\tag{5}
$$
with one rotation matrix for each index. Since $F_{ab}$ is antisymmetric, we can represent it using only three components like this:
$$
 v_m\equiv\sum_{j,k}\epsilon_{jkm}F_{jk}
\tag{6}
$$
The question is, how does $v$ transform under a rotation whose determinant is $+1$? To answer this, use (5) to get
$$
 v_m\to 
 v_m'=\sum_{j,k}\epsilon_{jkm}\sum_{a,b}R_{aj}R_{bk}F_{ab}
\tag{7}
$$
and then use (4) to get
$$
 v_m' =\sum_{a,b,c}
  \sum_c\epsilon_{abc}R_{cm}F_{ab}
 =\sum_c R_{cm} v_m.
\tag{8}
$$
This shows that $v$ transforms like a vector under rotations whose determinant is $+1$.

For rotations whose determinant is $-1$ (reflections), the right-hand side of equation (1) is replaced by $-1$, which introduces a minus sign in equation (4), which ends up putting a minus sign in equation (8). That's why we call $v$ an *axial* vector instead of just a vector.

---

More generally, in $N$-dimensional space:

- *Pseudovector* and *axial vector* are synonymous with "completely antisymmetric tensor of rank $N-1$." Intuitively, an ordinary (polar) vector *has* only one index, and a pseudovector/axial vector is *missing* only one index. As a result, they both transform the same way under rotations, but *only* under rotations. They transform differently in other respects, including relfections and dilations.
- Under an arbitrary coordinate transform, a (polar) vector transforms as $v_{j}\to \Lambda^a_j v_{a}$.
- Under an arbitrary coordinate transform, a rank-2 tensor transforms as $F_{jk}\to \Lambda^a_j\Lambda^b_k F_{ab}$. (The components of $\Lambda$ are the partial derivatives of one coordinate system's coordinates with respect to the other's. Sums over repeated indices are implied.)
- If $N\neq 3$, then angular momentum is an antisymmetric rank-2 tensor (also called a **bivector**), not an axial vector. A bivector has 2 indices, but an axial vector has $N-1$ indices.
- To illustrate the different transformation laws for (polar) vectors and bivectors, consider a **dilation** ([also called **dilatation**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160496)) that multiplies the spatial coordinates by a constant factor $\kappa$. Then each factor of $\Lambda$ contributes one factor of $\kappa$, so $F_{jk}\to\kappa^2 F_{jk}$, but a vector goes like $v_j\to \kappa v_j$.

Axial vectors and bivectors are the same in 3d space, but they are not really vectors at all, even though they both happen to have 3 components in 3d space. If we *only consider rotations* (with determinant $+1$), then they might as well be vectors, but even that's only true in 3d space, not in other-dimensional spaces.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117951/discussion-on-answer-by-chiral-anomaly-showing-that-4d-rank-2-anti-symmetric-ten).

Answer (score 4):

1. OP is asking for the [branching rules](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=branching+rules) for
   $$\begin{align}H~:=~&O(3)\cr
   ~\cong~&\begin{pmatrix} O(3)&\cr &1\end{pmatrix}_{4\times 4}~~\cr
    ~\subseteq~& O(3,1)~=:~G.\end{align}\tag{1}$$
2. The 4-vector representation decomposes as
   $${\bf 4}~\cong~\underbrace{\bf 3}_{\text{vector}}\oplus \underbrace{\bf 1}_{\text{scalar}}.\tag{2}$$
3. Therefore the tensor product representation becomes
   $$\begin{align} {\bf 16} ~\cong~&
   {\bf 4}\otimes{\bf 4}\cr 
   ~\cong~&({\bf 3}\oplus {\bf 1})\otimes({\bf 3}\oplus {\bf 1})  \cr
   ~\cong~&{\bf 3}\otimes{\bf 3}\oplus 
   \overbrace{\underbrace{{\bf 3}\otimes{\bf 1} \oplus{\bf 1}\otimes{\bf 3}}_{~\cong~{\bf 3}_S ~ \oplus~ {\bf 3}_A}}^{\text{off-diagonal blocks}} \oplus {\bf 1}\otimes{\bf 1}.\tag{3}
   \end{align}$$
   Here ${\bf 3}_S$ and ${\bf 3}_A$ denote the symmetric and antisymmetric combination of the off-diagonal blocks, respectively.
4. The symmetric part of the tensor product ${\bf 4}\otimes{\bf 4}$ reads
   $${\bf 10}~\cong~ {\bf 4}\odot{\bf 4} 
   ~\cong~\underbrace{{\bf 3}\odot {\bf 3}}_{~\cong~{\bf 5} ~ \oplus~ {\bf 1}}\oplus 
   {\bf 3}_S  \oplus {\bf 1},\tag{4}
   $$
   while the antisymmetric part is

   > $$ {\bf 6}~\cong~{\bf 4}\wedge{\bf 4} 
   > ~\cong~\underbrace{{\bf 3}\wedge {\bf 3}}_{\text{axial vector}}\oplus 
   > \underbrace{{\bf 3}_A}_{\text{vector}} ,\tag{5}
   > $$

   cf. OP's title question. In eq. (5) we used [Hodge duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator) in 3D, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130098/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 0):

Reference : My answer here [Vector product in a 4-dimensional Minkowski spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192997/vector-product-in-a-4-dimensional-minkowski-spacetime/600912#600912).

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=$

In my above referenced answer from two 4-vectors $\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathbf{x},x_4\right)$ and $\mathbf{P}\boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathbf{p},p_4\right)$, see also equations (15a) and (15b) therein, we had defined as their outer product the antisymmetric $4\times 4$ matrix
\begin{equation}
\left[\,\mathbf{H}\,\right] \boldsymbol{=}\left[\,\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{P}\,\right]\boldsymbol{\equiv}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
\hphantom{\boldsymbol{=}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm h_3 &  \boldsymbol{+}\mathrm h_2 & \boldsymbol{+}\mathrm g_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
 \boldsymbol{+}\mathrm h_3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{=}}0 & \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm h_1 & \boldsymbol{+}\mathrm g_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\boldsymbol{-}\mathrm h_2 & \boldsymbol{+}\mathrm h_1 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{=}}0 & \boldsymbol{+}\mathrm g_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\hline
\boldsymbol{-}\mathrm g_1 & \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm g_2 & \boldsymbol{-}\mathrm g_3 & \hphantom{\boldsymbol{=}}0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
&  &   & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
& \mathbf{h}\boldsymbol{\times} & & \mathbf{g} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
 &  &  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
\hline
 & \boldsymbol{-}\mathbf{g}^{\mathsf{T}} &  & 0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-01}\label{A-01} 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{h}\boldsymbol{=}\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{p}\,,\quad \mathbf{g}\boldsymbol{=}x_4\mathbf{p}\boldsymbol{-}p_4\mathbf{x}
\tag{A-02}\label{A-02} 
\end{equation}
For the details of this definition see equations (16)-(21) therein.

Moreover, based on this, from the space-time position and relativistic linear momentum of a particle respectively
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{=}\left(\mathbf{x}, ct\right) \qquad \mathbf{P} \boldsymbol{=}\left(\gamma m_{0}\mathbf{u}, \gamma m_{0} c\right)
\tag{A-03}\label{A-03}  
\end{equation}
we had defined as  *relativistic angular momentum* the   antisymmetric $4\times 4$ matrix
\begin{equation}
\left[\,\mathbf{H}\,\right] 
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
&  &   & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
& \left[\,\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{p}\,\right] & & \left(ct\mathbf{p}\boldsymbol{-}\gamma m_{0}c\mathbf{x}\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\right) \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
 &  &  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\hline
 & \boldsymbol{-}\left(ct\,\mathbf{p}\boldsymbol{-}\gamma m_{0}c\,\mathbf{x}\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\right)^{\mathsf{T}} &  & 0\vphantom{\dfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{b}} 
\end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-04}\label{A-04}  
\end{equation}
the  real 6-vector  $\mathbf{H}$ being (as in the question)
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H} \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{h}\vphantom{\dfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\\
\mathbf{g}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{p}\vphantom{\dfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\\
ct\mathbf{p}\boldsymbol{-}\gamma m_{0}c\mathbf{x}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-05}\label{A-05}   
\end{equation}
It's interesting to see how the  antisymmetric $4\times 4$ matrix $\left[\,\mathbf{H}\,\right]$  of equation \eqref{A-01} is transformed under a Lorentz boost
\begin{equation}
\mathrm L
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
 &  &   & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
&\mathrm I\boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}^{\mathsf{T}} & & \boldsymbol{-}\gamma\dfrac{\boldsymbol{\upsilon}}{c}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\   
 &  &  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\hline
 & \boldsymbol{-}\gamma\dfrac{\boldsymbol{\upsilon}^{\mathsf{T}}}{c} &  & \gamma\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}} 
\end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-06}\label{A-06}     
\end{equation}
We have
\begin{equation}
\left[\,\mathbf{H}'\,\right] \boldsymbol{=}\left[\,\mathbf{X}'\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{P}'\,\right]\boldsymbol{=}\left[\,\left(\mathrm L\mathbf{X}\right)\boldsymbol{\times}\left(\mathrm L\mathbf{P}\right)\,\right]\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm L\left[\,\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{P}\,\right]\mathrm L \boldsymbol{=}\mathrm L\left[\,\mathbf{H}\,\right]\mathrm L
\tag{A-07}\label{A-07}  
\end{equation}
hence
\begin{equation}
\left[\,\mathbf{H}'\,\right] \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
&  &   & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
& \mathbf{h}'\boldsymbol{\times} & & \mathbf{g}' \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
 &  &  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
\hline
 & \boldsymbol{-}\mathbf{g}'^{\mathsf{T}} &  & 0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-08}\label{A-08}  
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
\mathbf{h}' & \boldsymbol{=}
\gamma\mathbf{h}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{h}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\right)\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\vphantom{A^{1/2}}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma}{c}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{g}\vphantom{A^2}\right)
\tag{A-09a}\label{A-09a}\\
\mathbf{g}' & \boldsymbol{=}\gamma\mathbf{g}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{g}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\vphantom{A^2}\right)\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{\gamma}{c}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{h}\vphantom{A^2}\right)
\tag{A-09b}\label{A-09b}
\end{align}
If, by a similar way, we apply the Lorentz boost \eqref{A-06} to the antisymmetric matrix of the electromagnetic field
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E\!\!\!\!E}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
&  &   & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
& \left[\,c\,\mathbf{B}\,\right] & & \boldsymbol{+}\mathbf{E} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\   
 &  &  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\hline
 & \boldsymbol{-}\mathbf{E}^{\boldsymbol{\top}} &  & 0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
0 & \boldsymbol{-}c\,B_3 &  \boldsymbol{+}c\,B_2 & \boldsymbol{+}E_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
\boldsymbol{+}c\,B_3 & 0 & \boldsymbol{-}c\,B_1 & \boldsymbol{+}E_2 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\   
\boldsymbol{-}c\,B_2 & \boldsymbol{+}c\,B_1 & 0 & \boldsymbol{+}E_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\hline
\boldsymbol{-}E_1 & \boldsymbol{-}E_2 & \boldsymbol{-}E_3 & 0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{array} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\tag{A-10}\label{A-10}  
\end{equation}
see equations (28)-(31) in my referenced answer, then we have
\begin{align}
\mathbf{B}' & \boldsymbol{=}
\gamma \mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\right)\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\vphantom{A^{1/2}}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma}{c^2}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}\vphantom{A^{1/2}}\right) 
\tag{A-11a}\label{A-11a}\\
\mathbf{E}' & \boldsymbol{=}
\gamma\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\vphantom{A^2}\right)\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{+}\gamma\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}\vphantom{A^2}\right)
\tag{A-11b}\label{A-11b}
\end{align}
as we meet in many textbooks and answers in PSE.

Under the $4\times 4$ transformation
\begin{equation}
\mathrm R
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
 &  &   & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
&\hphantom{==}\mathcal R \hphantom{==}& & \hphantom{=}\mathbf{O}\hphantom{=}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\   
 &  &  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\hline
 & \mathbf{O}^{\boldsymbol{\top}} &  & 1\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}} 
\end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-12}\label{A-12}     
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal R$ is an orthonormal $3\times 3$ matrix
\begin{equation}
\mathcal R \mathcal R^{\mathsf{T}}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm I_{3\times 3}\boldsymbol{=}\mathcal R^{\mathsf{T}}\mathcal R
\,,\qquad  \boldsymbol{\vert} \det(\mathcal R)\boldsymbol{\vert}\boldsymbol{=}1
\tag{A-13}\label{A-13}      
\end{equation}
the  antisymmetric $4\times 4$ matrix $\left[\,\mathbf{H}\,\right]$  of equation \eqref{A-01} is transformed as follows
\begin{equation}
\left[\,\mathbf{H}'\,\right] \boldsymbol{=}\left[\,\mathbf{X}'\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{P}'\,\right]\boldsymbol{=}\left[\,\left(\mathrm R\mathbf{X}\right)\boldsymbol{\times}\left(\mathrm R\mathbf{P}\right)\,\right]\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm R\left[\,\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{P}\,\right]\mathrm R^{\mathsf{T}} 
\tag{A-14}\label{A-14}  
\end{equation}
hence
\begin{equation}
\left[\,\mathbf{H}'\,\right] \boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
&  &   & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
& \mathbf{h}'\boldsymbol{\times} & & \mathbf{g}' \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
 &  &  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
\hline
 & \boldsymbol{-}\mathbf{g}'^{\mathsf{T}} &  & 0\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-15}\label{A-15}  
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align} 
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mathbf{h}'\boldsymbol{\times} & \boldsymbol{=}
\mathcal R \left(\mathbf{h}\boldsymbol{\times}\right)\mathcal  R^{\mathsf{T}}\boldsymbol{=}\mathcal R \left[\left(\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{p}\right)\boldsymbol{\times}\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\right]\mathcal  R^{\mathsf{T}}
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=}\left[\mathcal R\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathcal  R\mathbf{p}\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\right]\boldsymbol{\times}\stackrel{\eqref{A-18}}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=}}\det(\mathcal R)\cdot\left[\mathcal R \left(\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{p}\right)\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\right]\boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{=}\det(\mathcal R)\cdot\mathcal R\mathbf{h}\boldsymbol{\times}\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}
\nonumber\\
\mathbf{h}'& \boldsymbol{=}\det(\mathcal R)\cdot\mathcal R\mathbf{h}
\tag{A-16a}\label{A-16a}\\
\mathbf{g}' & \boldsymbol{=}\mathcal R \mathbf{g}
\tag{A-16b}\label{A-16b} 
\end{align}

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=$

If $\:\mathbf{a},\:\mathbf{b} $ are complex $\:3$-vectors  in $\:\mathbb{C}^{3}\:$ and $\:\mathcal M\:$ an invertible linear transformation in this space then
\begin{equation}
\mathcal M\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times} \mathcal M\mathbf{b} \boldsymbol{=}
\left[\;\det\left(\mathcal M\right)\cdot\left(\mathcal M^{-1}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\; \right]\left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right) 
\tag{A-17}\label{A-17}
\end{equation}
If moreover $\:\mathcal M\:$  is a real orthonormal matrix then $\left(\mathcal M^{-1}\right)^{\mathsf{T}}\boldsymbol{=}\mathcal M$ and $\det\left(\mathcal M\right)\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}1$ hence
\begin{equation}
\mathcal M\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times} \mathcal M\mathbf{b} \boldsymbol{=} \det\left(\mathcal M\right)\cdot\mathcal M\left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\pm}\,\mathcal M\left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right) 
\tag{A-18}\label{A-18}
\end{equation}
For a proof of identity \eqref{A-17} see $\textbf{Section B}$ in my answer as user82794 (former diracpaul) here

[How to get result $\boldsymbol{3}\boldsymbol{\otimes}\boldsymbol{3} =\boldsymbol{6}\boldsymbol{\oplus}\bar{\boldsymbol{3}}$ for SU(3) irreducible representations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147243/how-to-get-result-3-otimes-3-6-oplus-bar3-for-su3-irreducible-repre)