# How to write a matrix $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M} \boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\boldsymbol{x}$?

Tags: operators, rotation, linear-algebra

As is well known, it is possible to use the $\nabla$ operator as if it were a vector.  Someone consider it an abuse of notation but surely something that works well and is very useful. Well, how is it possible to consider the operator $\boldsymbol{\omega}\times$ as a matrix? How build a matrix $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{x} = \mathcal{M} \boldsymbol{x}$?

Comment: Duplicate : [Vector cross product formula without a second term](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/671889/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vector cross product formula without a second term (Spiegel, Theoretical Mechanics)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/671889/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$  [\mathbf{a}]_{\times} = \begin{bmatrix}
      \,\,0 &  \!-a_3 & \,\,\,a_2 \\
  \,\,\,a_3 &       0 &    \!-a_1 \\
     \!-a_2 & \,\,a_1 &     \,\,0
\end{bmatrix}, $$

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Cross_product

Answer (score 7):

The present answer is already correct, just let me show how to get the result. Using Einstein convention (i.e. repeated indices are summed) the product $c = a \times b$ can be written as

$$
c_i = (a \times b)_i =\epsilon_{ijk} \, a_j \,  b_k = A_{ik} b_k
$$

where $\epsilon_{ijk} $ is the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) and the matrix $A$ is defined by $A_{ik}=\epsilon_{ijk} \, a_j=-\epsilon_{iks} \, a_s$.
It is easy to see that $A$ is skew-symmetric, i.e. $A_{lm} =-A_{ml}$. This trick will be useful to study the [$SO(3)$ group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group) and its associated algebra $so(3)$.